# Recommendation for KVM Switch with 2 monitors and USB-C ports

Tags: multiple-monitors, kvm, switch

I am looking for a KVM switch that uses USB-C and supports 2 monitors. I prefer the USB-C to avoid extra cables. Also if dual monitor is not available, a single monitor KVM switch would be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this KVM on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Sabrent-2-Port-Type-C-Delivery-USB-KCPD/dp/B07Y2HKN37?th=1). It has a Type C port available with 2 monitors connectivity. But the cost is very high. It cost around 100$.

I am wondering why you don't try KVM software if you have a decent internet connection.

Personally, I am using KVM software to access my sister's computer sometimes & it works pretty well for me.

I am referring to one guide here. https://trustedmonitors.com/connect-two-computers-to-one-monitor-without-kvm/

Comment: The link is broken - it goes to advertising blurb for the company.

Answer (score 0):

Another option with 2 monitors:
https://a.co/d/8lC0u0F